# Translate language of web page

Tags: jasperserver

i translate the jasperserver_message.properties to amharic which contain label and message used in the main jasper reports server user interfaceand saved jasperserver_message_am.properties.but it shows the word like these...

> áá° á¢ááµá¤ áªáá­áµ ááá¥á áªá« á¥áá³á á
>   á°áá áá¡

*i specified the locale in applicationContext-security.xml*

```
bean id="userLocalesList"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.common.LocalesListImpl">
<property name="locales">
    <list>
        <value type="java.util.Locale">en</value>
        <value type="java.util.Locale">fr</value>
        <value type="java.util.Locale">it</value>
        <value type="java.util.Locale">de</value>
        <value type="java.util.Locale">ro</value>
        <value type="java.util.Locale">ja</value>
        <value type="java.util.Locale">am</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

what can i do?

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) explains how to ask a well-defined question about encoding problems. We can't guess which encoding this is without seeing some of the *actual* data, not just how it is incorrectly rendered in an unknown encoding in an  unspecified browser from data we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

use these website ([[1]: https://www.branah.com/]) and convert (key=value)the value to UTF-16 and place to value of key 
  for example:
       key=value
       LOGIN_WELCOME_OS=Welcome to Jaspersoft
             and when u localize change the value(Welcome to Jaspersoft) to your language and convert ur languge to UTF-16 using these https://www.branah.com/ website

```
   like:- LOGIN_WELCOME_OS=ወደ ጃስፐርሶፕ እንኳን በደህና መጡ
   then change the value to UTF-16
```

LOGIN_WELCOME_OS =\u12c8\u12f0 \u1303\u1235\u1350\u122d\u1236\u1355 \u12a5\u1295\u12b3 \u1295 \u1260\u12f0\u1205\u1293 \u1218\u1321

Answer (score -3):

You have to convert to ascii format. Please use this command "**native2ascii jasperserver_message_am.properties jasperserver_message_am_converted.properties**" . Please rename converted(Output) file to "jasperserver_message_am.properties" and replace in "WEB-INF\bundles" folders and restart Tomcat. As an alternative you can use this site *https://native2ascii.net/* for converting to ascii.

Comment: This might be a useful utility for some scenarios, but does nothing to solve the problem in the question at the top of this page. Amharic - like most of the world's languages - is not representable in ASCII. The site simply seems to convert the input to hex escapes anyway.